# command line arguments not returned properly

Tags: c#

I'm totally new and study myself in c# , I found this example from internet

```
// cmdline1.cs
// arguments: A B C
using System;

public class CommandLine
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // The Length property is used to obtain the length of the array. 
       // Notice that Length is a read-only property:
       Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}",
          args.Length);
       for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
    }
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
Number of command line parameters = 3
Arg[0] = [A]
Arg[1] = [B]
Arg[2] = [C]
```

I tried this code on [RexTester](http://rextester.com/runcode) but the output is:

```
Number of command line parameters = 1
Arg[0] = [parameter for the curious]
```

How the output will have A B and C ?

Comment: What's the command line you specified?

Comment: Are you asking how command line arguments work in general, or how to get the output on Rextester?

Comment: Because it looks like Rextester doesn't handle command line arguments, even when you click the "input" link.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the program from the command line. Open a command prompt, change directory to the bin/Debug (or bin/Release, depending on how you bulit it) directory and run your command like so:

```
commandline.exe A B C
```

Answer (score 1):

The output will have `A`, `B`, and `C` because you specify that when you run the program.

If you run the program outside the debugger, you do this simply by providing those values on the command line. For example:

> CommandLine A B C

If you are running the program in Visual Studio using the debugger, you can provide the command line arguments in the "Debug" pane of the Project Properties window. Just enter then in the "Command line arguments" text box, exactly as you would have provided them on the command line (without the executable name itself, of course).

If you are running the program via the `RexTester` utility, then I have no idea how you provide command line arguments. It's not possible as far as I know (but I could be missing something).

Comment: how to open the Project Settings window ? I now using the visual studio 2012 to try out this code but the output is `Number of command line parameters = 0`

Comment: There are lots of ways to get to the window. Try the "Project" menu...you can open the project settings (aka "properties") with the menu item at the bottom. Another way is to right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and choose the "Properties" menu item.